# How to autovectorize a loop with access stride 2 with g++ without openCL or intrinsics

Tags: gcc, g++, simd, auto-vectorization

I am trying to convert a function from an implementation using intrinsics into standard C++ (to simplify maintenance, portability, etc.). Everything worked fine, except for a loop with stride 2 where bytes at odd positions are gathered into one location and bytes at odd positions are gathered into another location.

Related questions have been addressed using opencl or intrinsics, but I would like to stick to standard c++.

A minimal example of what I am trying to auto-vectorize would be something like this:

```
void f(const unsigned char *input, const unsigned size, unsigned char *output) {
  constexpr unsigned MAX_SIZE = 2000;
  unsigned char odd[MAX_SIZE / 2];
  unsigned char even[MAX_SIZE / 2];
  for (unsigned i = 0; size > i; ++i) {
    if (0 == i % 2) {even[i/2] = input[i];}
    else {odd[i/2] = input[i];}
  }
  //for (unsigned i = 0; size > i; i+=2) {
  //  even[i/2] = input[i];
  //  odd[i/2] = input[i+1];
  //}
  for (unsigned i = 0; size / 2 > i; ++i)
  {
    output[i] = (even[i] << 4) | odd[i];
  }
```

}

Compiling with g++-11.2, the output of -fopt-info-vec-missed is:

```
minimal.cpp:6:29: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
minimal.cpp:6:29: missed: not vectorized: control flow in loop.
```

If I change the implementation to the one that is commented out in the code, g++ fails to vectorize because:

```
minimal.cpp:11:29: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
minimal.cpp:13:24: missed: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _13 = *_11;
```

Considering that it is straightforward to implement this with packed shuffle bytes instructions, I am surprised that g++ can't do it.

Is there a way to re-write the loop so that g++ would be able to vectorize it?

Comment: “I am surprised that g++ can't do it.” I’m not. Automatic vectorization is a “sufficiently smart compiler” class of problems, borderline impossible to solve in general. YMMV but based on my observations, for vertical-only FP32 and FP64 math, modern C++ compilers are often OK; for anything else they fail in more than 50% cases.

Comment: Clang13 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512 vectorizes the second version.  https://godbolt.org/z/b4G4jojn1 It's a bit clunky but vastly better than scalar.  Using `vpmovwb` for one of the stores, to get the even elements, but some shuffling on both halves of a load to get the odd elements. Maybe it'd be less bad with just SSE4 or `-mprefer-vector-width=128`?  Nope, still doesn't think of left-shifting to feed `vpmovwb`. 
 With `-mno-avx`, we get a janky mix of `pshufb`/`punpcklqdq` and `pand`/`packuswb` https://godbolt.org/z/E4fPjjMo8  (Use `-fno-unroll-loops` to see one vector worth of clang's strat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I found @Peter Cordes 's comment and I combined with my initial answer:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bxzsfxPGx

and `-fopt-info-vec-missed` doesn't say anything to me

```
void f(const unsigned char *input, const unsigned size, unsigned char *output) {
    constexpr unsigned MAX_SIZE = 2000;
    unsigned char odd[MAX_SIZE / 2];
    unsigned char even[MAX_SIZE / 2];
    for (unsigned i = 0, j = 0; size > i; i += 2, ++j) {
        even[j] = input[i];
        odd[j] = input[i + 1];
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; size / 2 > i; ++i) {
        output[i] = (even[i] << 4) | odd[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's not terrible, with that MAX size limit, it will fit in L1d.  (Update: was commenting on your previous version with split loops).  clang still wastes some `vpshufb`, but GCC does pretty nicely with `vpand` to feed `vpackuswb` / `vpermq`.  I tried removing the tmp arrays, and GCC actually does manage to auto-vectorize!  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b3fhzv9ej (So does clang, but it's nasty)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm not sure if putting `__restrict` aligns with author's goal. It is likely so, but it could be that having intermediate buffers is precisely to handle aliasing. If so, maybe removing `__restrict` still does not prevent vectorization, just adds check for aliasing.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Yeah, I wondered about that; hadn't gotten around to checking if it still vectorized without `__restrict`; I added that early on, before trying other ideas.

Comment: This does work very well with gcc 11.2 indeed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It seems GCC doesn't like stuff like `i<size ; i += 2`.  Instead, it liked `i<size/2 ; i++`.  GCC and clang can't auto-vectorize loops whose trip-count  can't be determined ahead of time.  Perhaps GCC has a problem with this because you used `unsigned`, so `i+=2` could wrap back to `0` without ever hitting `size`, so `i<size` could be permanently false, i.e. **the compiler can't prove your loop isn't infinite because `size = UINT_MAX` is possible.**  (Which disables some optimizations compilers like to do, although at least it's unsigned so we don't have to redo sign extension.)

Clang managed to vectorize anyway (poorly: https://godbolt.org/z/b4G4jojn1); possibly it realized that `evens[i]` would be UB if greater than the constant MAX_SIZE, or else it just didn't care.

---

The temporary arrays seem unnecessary; I think you were only using them to try to give GCC multiple simpler problems to vectorize?

```
// __restrict is optional; it promises the compiler input and output won't overlap
// it still vectorizes without it, but does a check for overlap

void g(const unsigned char *__restrict input, const unsigned size, unsigned char *__restrict output)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0 ; size/2 > i; i++) {
        output[i] = (input[2*i] << 4) | input[2*i+1];
    }
}
```

Without `__restrict`, on overlap it falls back to a scalar loop.  In the case of `input = output` exactly, the vector version is still safe.  I didn't test or reverse-engineer the overlap check to see whether it uses the vectorized version or not in that case.  (It would be C++ UB to use it with `input=output` with `__restrict`, though.)

GCC11.2 `-O3 -march=haswell` auto-vectorizes this fairly reasonably ([Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%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%2BhoHIWG2UIqmYR5hqeF5rsmZkEC%2B951hAKkmmYXyZm%2BH5fkBP6hXK4WhpYXAAb5YGgcBdocPMtCcDKvB%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%2BswYg0NgZUVBgQCGUNVpwwRkjYqKM04Y1WtjXG70BaE0qKtUm5NKYYDrg1TCDNuB7WZkwVmHNua835jw8WwtxBi34IIRQKh1Aw10OsfQCMUAKxYcrbeasNacC1gQHWnI9aj0NsbdYRtLavBtmbe2tBaBG34OrTiwR%2BCcSNMgC2NElDoCdu0Zwj53YF1aIELO0x%2BjrCxGHPI6R/HhIjiXEJYS7BpwTvnZOocEnxxqBnWJ/t4nJKyKkzJQS/YSCxOXSuotOG10ZotDgjdf5rTbh3LuYlkDIHrFwfqHlh4K3HvgIgSJp7bFnpA/pZh1jrGXkA3aa9SCtXapQbqEg%2BTVOWqQBmcQND7z6mfeIGhJojUfjKJuq1/62EATtLQ0yepP36mMrEfJ35YhlDKLgMpxqtGJusFaMMTnnOatUswXyW7rUmRc%2BYvFUjOEkEAA%3D%3D)); some missed optimizations but not as bad as with separate loops, and of course avoids touching new stack memory.  The main inner loop looks like this:

```
# GCC11 -O3 -march=haswell
# before loop, YMM3 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x00FF)
.L4:                                              # do{
        vpand   ymm1, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+32+rax*2]  # why not reuse the load results for both odd/even?  fortunately modern CPUs have good L1d bandwidth
        vpand   ymm0, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax*2]     # evens: load input[2*(i+0..31)]  and AND away the high bytes for pack
        vmovdqu ymm4, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax*2]       # load 2 vectors of input data
        vmovdqu ymm5, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+32+rax*2]
        vpackuswb       ymm0, ymm0, ymm1            # evens: pack evens down to single bytes.
        vpsrlw  ymm2, ymm5, 8                       # odds: shift down to line up with evens
        vpsrlw  ymm1, ymm4, 8
        vpermq  ymm0, ymm0, 216                     # evens: lane-crossing fixup
        vpaddb  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0                # evens <<= 1 byte shift (x86 SIMD lacks a vpsllb, even with AVX-512)
        vpackuswb       ymm1, ymm1, ymm2            # odds: pack
        vpaddb  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0                # evens <<= 1
        vpermq  ymm1, ymm1, 216                     # odds: lane-crossing fixup
        vpaddb  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0                # evens <<= 1
        vpaddb  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0                # evens <<= 1
        vpor    ymm0, ymm0, ymm1                    # (evens<<4) | odds
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], ymm0         # store to output
        add     rax, 32                             # advance output position by 32 bytes.  (Input positions scale by 2)
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L4                              # } while(i != size/2)
```

---

It would have been faster if GCC had chosen to mask with `0x000F` instead of `0x00FF` before packing, so the packed evens could be left-shifted with `vpsllw` instead of 4x `vpaddb` without spilling any non-zero bits into the next byte.  Or just shift and AND again; that's the standard way to emulate the non-existent `vpsllb`.

Or even better, OR together high and low within each word *before* packing down to bytes.

```
# manually vectorized;  what GCC could have done in theory
# if using intrinsics, this strategy is probably good.
    vmovdqu  ymm0, [mem]
    vmovdqu  ymm1, [mem+32]
    vpsllw   ymm2, ymm0, 12          # evens: line up with odds, and do the <<4
    vpsllw   ymm3, ymm1, 12
    vpor     ymm0, ymm0, ymm2        # odds |= (evens<<4) in the high byte of each word
    vpor     ymm1, ymm1, ymm3
    vpsrlw   ymm0, ymm0, 8           # shift merged to bottom of word
    vpsrlw   ymm1, ymm1, 8
    vpackuswb ymm0, ymm0, ymm1       # and pack
    vpermq   ymm0, ymm0, 0xDB   # same 216
    vmovdqu [mem], ymm0
    .. pointer increment / loop condition
```

Notice that we avoided an AND constant; both halves needed shifting anyway (odd to be in the right place for pack, even because of `<<4`).  Shifting after packing would mean half as much data to shift, but would have needed masking after the shift so it's break except for back-end port pressure on ALU ports with shift units. (https://agner.org/optimize/ ; https://uops.info/).  But merging before packing saves shuffles, and that's a bigger throughput bottleneck on Intel CPUs.

---

If we can add instead of OR (because we know there aren't overlapping bits so it's equivalent), we could 2x `vpmaddubsw` (`_mm256_maddubs_epi16`) using the signed (second) operand as a `_mm256_set1_epi16(0x0110)` and the unsigned (first) input holding data from the array to do `input[2*i+1] + (input[2*i] * 16)` within each byte pair.  Then AND and VPACKUSWB / VPERMQ from words down to byte elements and store.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed analysis Peter. I had to select Igor's answer though.

Comment: @ComeRaczy: Ok, up to you which answer you think is best.  I think the code in my answer shows a better more efficient way to write the function, which still makes the compiler split up odd/even when vectorizing, i.e. still strided loads.  IIRC, storing to temporary arrays and then looping over them is pure overhead, so I'd expect my version to be faster.